# Complex canvas in view killing recyclerview scroll

Tags: android, canvas, android-recyclerview

Below is code we're using to draw a weather graph that shows as a view in a recyclerview.  When approaching this view, the list scroll takes a dive as the canvas is drawn.

Can anybody suggest a way to smooth this out?  Maybe a way to draw in background or a better way to do the drawing?

```
public class WeatherHourlyForecastGraphView extends View {
    private static String LOG_TAG = WeatherHourlyForecastGraphView.class.getSimpleName();

    private static int TEMPERATURE = 0;
    private static int PRECIPITATION = 1;
    private static final String TIME_FORMAT = "h a";

    // public static final int GRAPH_HEIGHT_PHONE = 145;
    // public static final int GRAPH_HEIGHT_TABLET = 188;

    public static final int GRAPH_TOP = (DeviceInfo.isDeviceAPhone() ? 145 : 186);
    public static final int GRAPH_DISPLAY_HEIGHT = GRAPH_TOP - 9;  // 100 will be displayed at GRAPH_DISPLAY_HEIGHT

    private Rect mTextBounds;

    // Handle hour in graph being tapped
    public interface OnHourSelectionListener {
        void onHourSelected(int selectedPosition);
    }

    // Temperature and precipitation values
    private ArrayList<Double> mPrecipitationValues = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Double> mTemperatureValues = new ArrayList<>();

    // Current city for weather - retrieve hourly for this city
    private City mCurrentCityWeather;

    // Icons
    private HashMap<String, Bitmap> mWeatherConditionIcons = new HashMap<>();
    private Bitmap mPrecipitationIcon;

    // Paint
    private Paint mTemperaturePaint;
    private Paint mPrecipitationPaint;
    private Paint mPrecipitationLinePaint;
    private Paint mGraphPaperLinePaint;
    private Paint mDotPaint;
    private Paint mWhitePaint;
    private Paint mTimeTextPaint;
    private Paint mTemperatureTextPaint;
    private Paint mPrecipitationTextPaint;
    private Paint mSelectedPaint;

    // When hour is selected. Redraw graph, update conditions
    private int mSelectedPosition;
    private OnHourSelectionListener mOnHourSelectionListener;
    private GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener gestureListener = new GestureListener();
    private final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(getContext(), gestureListener);

    // Width (x -values) for displaying single hour in graph
    private int mHalfHourlyDisplayWidth;
    private int mHourlyDisplayWidth;

    private int timeTopPadding;
    private int iconTopPadding;
    private int tempTopPadding;
    private int precipTopPadding;
    private int mGraphHeightWithPadding;
    private int mContentHeight;
    private RectF mIconRectF;
    private int numHours = 24;
    private Paint backgroundPaint;
    private Path tempGeneratePath;

    private MyNews myNews;
    ArrayList<Double> pathValues;

    public WeatherHourlyForecastGraphView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public WeatherHourlyForecastGraphView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public WeatherHourlyForecastGraphView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public WeatherHourlyForecastGraphView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    {
        mIconRectF = new RectF();
        backgroundPaint = new Paint();
        tempGeneratePath = new Path();
        myNews = MyNews.getMyNews();
        pathValues = new ArrayList<>();

        initializePaintsInUse();
        initializeDimensions();
        mPrecipitationIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.rain_drop);

        mTextBounds = new Rect(); // Used to calculate the text bounds while drawing. Initialize in constructor to avoid creating object in onDraw()
        // setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    }

    private void initializePaintsInUse() {
        mTemperaturePaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mTemperaturePaint.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.hourly_forecast_graph_temperature_color));
        mTemperaturePaint.setStrokeWidth(3);
        mTemperaturePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

        mPrecipitationPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mPrecipitationPaint.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.hourly_forecast_graph_precip_color));
        mPrecipitationPaint.setStrokeWidth(3);

        mPrecipitationLinePaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mPrecipitationLinePaint.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.hourly_forecast_graph_precip_line_color));
        mPrecipitationLinePaint.setStrokeWidth(3);
        mPrecipitationLinePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

        mGraphPaperLinePaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mGraphPaperLinePaint.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.hourly_forecast_graph_paper_line_color));
        mGraphPaperLinePaint.setStrokeWidth(1);
        mGraphPaperLinePaint.setPathEffect(null);
        mGraphPaperLinePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

        mWhitePaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mWhitePaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        mWhitePaint.setStrokeWidth(DeviceInfo.getValuesInPixel(1));

        mSelectedPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mSelectedPaint.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.hourly_forecast_graph_selected_item_color));
        mSelectedPaint.setStrokeWidth(2);

        mDotPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mDotPaint.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.pale_blue));
        mDotPaint.setStrokeWidth(2);

        mTimeTextPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mTimeTextPaint.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.hourly_forecast_graph_time_text_color));
        mTimeTextPaint.setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.hourly_forecast_graph_time_text_size));
        mTimeTextPaint.setTypeface(FontManager.getInstance().get(getResources().getString(R.string.roboto_medium_font), Typeface.NORMAL));

        mTemperatureTextPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mTemperatureTextPaint.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.hourly_forecast_graph_temperature_text_color));
        mTemperatureTextPaint.setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.hourly_forecast_graph_temperature_text_size));
        mTemperatureTextPaint.setTypeface(DeviceInfo.isDeviceAPhone() ? Typeface.create(getResources().getString(R.string.roboto), Typeface.NORMAL)
                : FontManager.getInstance().get(getResources().getString(R.string.roboto_medium_font), Typeface.NORMAL));

        mPrecipitationTextPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mPrecipitationTextPaint.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.hourly_forecast_graph_temperature_precipitation_color));
        mPrecipitationTextPaint.setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.hourly_forecast_graph_precipitation_text_size));
        mPrecipitationTextPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.create(getResources().getString(R.string.roboto), Typeface.NORMAL));  // was roboto light
    }

    private void initializeDimensions() {
        // Width when displaying weather for single hour
        mHourlyDisplayWidth = DeviceInfo.getValuesInPixel(DeviceInfo.isDeviceAPhone() ? 65 : 101);  // was 55, 85
        mHalfHourlyDisplayWidth = mHourlyDisplayWidth / 2;
        // mGraphHeightWithPadding = DeviceInfo.getValuesInPixel(DeviceInfo.isDeviceAPhone() ? 145 : 188);
        mGraphHeightWithPadding = DeviceInfo.getValuesInPixel(GRAPH_TOP);

        mContentHeight = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.hourly_forecast_content_height);
        timeTopPadding = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.hourly_forecast_content_time_top_padding);
        iconTopPadding = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.hourly_forecast_content_icon_top_padding);
        tempTopPadding = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.hourly_forecast_content_temperature_top_padding);
        precipTopPadding = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.hourly_forecast_content_precipitation_top_padding);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(MeasureSpec.getSize(numHours * mHourlyDisplayWidth), MeasureSpec.getSize(mGraphHeightWithPadding + mContentHeight));
    }

    /**
     * This view's onDraw method
     * Uses 2 bitmaps to paint each half of graph (Hardware LayerType supports only particular length)
     * That avoids issue of path disappearing
     * See issues related to canvas rescaling here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html
     *
     * @param canvas the canvas to draw
     */
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // FIXME: Move object allocations out of onDraw(). Also look for object allocations in the methods called by onDraw() as well
        // Create left bitmap
        Bitmap bitmapLeft = Bitmap.createBitmap(numHours / 2 * mHourlyDisplayWidth, canvas.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        bitmapLeft.setDensity(DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT);
        Canvas bitmapCanvasLeft = new Canvas(bitmapLeft);
        bitmapCanvasLeft.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        drawGraphBackground(bitmapCanvasLeft);

        // Create right bitmap
        Bitmap bitmapRight = Bitmap.createBitmap(numHours / 2 * mHourlyDisplayWidth, canvas.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        bitmapLeft.setDensity(DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT);
        Canvas bitmapCanvasRight = new Canvas(bitmapRight);
        bitmapCanvasRight.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        drawGraphBackground(bitmapCanvasRight);

        // Draw Temperature graph into each bitmap
        drawTemperatureGraph(bitmapCanvasLeft, 0);  // always call left side first
        drawTemperatureGraph(bitmapCanvasRight, 12);

        // Draw Precipitation graph into each bitmap
        drawPrecipitationGraph(bitmapCanvasLeft, 0);  // always call left side first
        drawPrecipitationGraph(bitmapCanvasRight, 12);

        // Draw bitmaps into canvas
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapLeft, 0f, 0f, null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapRight, numHours / 2 * mHourlyDisplayWidth, 0f, null);

        // Highlight selected hour
        drawSelectedHour(canvas);

        // Draw Graph lines
        drawGraphLines(canvas);

        // Draw text under graph
        drawText(canvas);
    }

    /**
     * Draw background including top/bottom colors and graph lines
     *
     * @param canvas the canvas to draw
     */
    private void drawGraphBackground(Canvas canvas) {
        backgroundPaint.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.hourly_forecast_graph_background_color));
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), mGraphHeightWithPadding, backgroundPaint);
    }

    private void drawTemperatureGraph(Canvas canvas, int start) {
        Path temperaturePath = generatePath(TEMPERATURE, start);
        canvas.drawPath(temperaturePath, mTemperaturePaint);
    }

    private void drawPrecipitationGraph(Canvas canvas, int start) {
        Path precipPath = generatePath(PRECIPITATION, start);
        // draw filled
        canvas.drawPath(precipPath, mPrecipitationPaint);
        // draw line around all
        canvas.drawPath(precipPath, mPrecipitationLinePaint);
        // hide bottom line
        canvas.drawLine(-5, mGraphHeightWithPadding, numHours * mHourlyDisplayWidth, mGraphHeightWithPadding, mPrecipitationPaint);
    }

    /**
     * Given a Temperature or Precipitation value to display, return Y value on graph
     *
     * @param valueToDisplay the graph value to be displayed
     * @return the y position on the graph
     */
    private float getGraphHeightForValue(double valueToDisplay) {
        // float topGraphValue = (float) (DeviceInfo.isDeviceAPhone() ? 145 * pixelHeight : 186 * pixelHeight);  // handle -2 to 112,  Temperature 0 is displayed 2 above bottom of graph
        // float displayHeight = (float) (DeviceInfo.isDeviceAPhone() ? 140 * pixelHeight: 181 * pixelHeight);  // handle -2 to 112,  Temperature 0 is displayed 2 above bottom of graph

        float topGraphValue = DeviceInfo.getValuesInPixel(GRAPH_TOP);  // handle -2 to 112,  Temperature 0 is displayed 2 above bottom of graph
        float displayHeight = DeviceInfo.getValuesInPixel(GRAPH_DISPLAY_HEIGHT);  // handle -2 to 112,  Temperature 0 is displayed 2 above bottom of graph

        float ratio = (float) (valueToDisplay / 100);  // 78 degrees = 78%,  103 degrees = 103%
        float y = ratio * displayHeight; // number of pixes out of 107);
        return topGraphValue - y;
    }

    /**
     * The selected hour is displayed as rectangle, vertical line through selected value, and circle around hour
     *
     * @param canvas the canvas to draw
     */
    private void drawSelectedHour(Canvas canvas) {
        // double selectedTemperature = mTemperatureValues.get(mSelectedPosition);
        float selectedX = mSelectedPosition * mHourlyDisplayWidth + mHalfHourlyDisplayWidth;

        // Draw line on graph
        mTemperaturePaint.setStrokeWidth(1);
        canvas.drawLine(selectedX, 0, selectedX, mGraphHeightWithPadding, mTemperaturePaint);

        mTemperaturePaint.setStrokeWidth(3);

        // Draw Rectangle on graph and text
        mSelectedPaint.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.hourly_forecast_graph_selected_item_color));
        // canvas.drawRect(selectedX-mHalfHourlyDisplayWidth, 0, selectedX+mHalfHourlyDisplayWidth, mGraphHeightWithPadding, mSelectedPaint );
        canvas.drawRect(selectedX - mHalfHourlyDisplayWidth, 0, selectedX + mHalfHourlyDisplayWidth, canvas.getHeight(), mSelectedPaint);

        // Draw Circles
        drawSelectedCircles(canvas);
    }

    private void drawGraphLines(Canvas canvas) {
        // draw horizontal lines at 0, 25,75, 100
        for (double i = 0; i <= 100; i += 25) {
            canvas.drawLine(0, getGraphHeightForValue(i), canvas.getWidth(), getGraphHeightForValue(i), mGraphPaperLinePaint);
        }

        // draw vertical lines in center of each hour unit
        for (int index = 0; index < numHours; index++) {
            float selectedX = index * mHourlyDisplayWidth;
            // float selectedX = index * mHourlyDisplayWidth + mHalfHourlyDisplayWidth;
            canvas.drawLine(selectedX, 0, selectedX, canvas.getHeight(), mGraphPaperLinePaint);
        }

        // redraw circles over graph lines
        drawSelectedCircles(canvas);
    }

    private void drawSelectedCircles(Canvas canvas) {
        double selectedTemperature = mTemperatureValues.get(mSelectedPosition);
        float selectedX = mSelectedPosition * mHourlyDisplayWidth + mHalfHourlyDisplayWidth;
        float selectedY = getGraphHeightForValue(selectedTemperature);
        mDotPaint.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.hourly_forecast_graph_temperature_color));
        canvas.drawCircle(selectedX, selectedY, getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.hourly_forecast_graph_selected_outer_circle_radius), mDotPaint);
        canvas.drawCircle(selectedX, selectedY, getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.hourly_forecast_graph_selected_middle_circle_radius), mWhitePaint);
        canvas.drawCircle(selectedX, selectedY, getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.hourly_forecast_graph_selected_inner_circle_radius), mDotPaint);
    }

    private void drawText(Canvas canvas) {
        int xAxisValue = mHalfHourlyDisplayWidth;
        float width, height;
        Bitmap bitmap;
        for (Hour hour : mCurrentCityWeather.hourlyForecast) {
            String value = hour.getLocalTime(TIME_FORMAT);

            // Draw Time Value
            width = mTimeTextPaint.measureText(value);
            height = mGraphHeightWithPadding + timeTopPadding + mTimeTextPaint.getTextSize();

            canvas.drawText(value, (xAxisValue - (width / 2)), height, mTimeTextPaint);

            // Draw Weather Conditions Icon
            bitmap = mWeatherConditionIcons.get(myNews.getGlobal().manifest.appBaseUrls.getWeatherConditionIconUrl(hour.iconCode));
            height += iconTopPadding;
            if (bitmap != null) {
                // Set width to 24 for handheld and large.  30 for extra large
                width = DeviceInfo.getValuesInPixel(24);
                if (DeviceInfo.isDeviceATablet()) {
                    String screenSize = DeviceInfo.getScreenType();
                    if (screenSize.equalsIgnoreCase("xlarge")) {
                        width = DeviceInfo.getValuesInPixel(30);
                    }
                }
                // width = DeviceInfo.getValuesInPixel(DeviceInfo.isDeviceAPhone() ? 24 : 30);
                // mIconRectF.set((xAxisValue - (width / 2)), height, (xAxisValue + (width / 2)), height +  DeviceInfo.getValuesInPixel(DeviceInfo.isDeviceAPhone() ? 24 : 30));
                mIconRectF.set((xAxisValue - (width / 2)), height, (xAxisValue + (width / 2)), height + width);
                canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, null, mIconRectF, null);
            }
            // height += DeviceInfo.getValuesInPixel(24);
            height += width;
            value = StringUtils.appendDegree(hour.getTemperature());
            // Draw Temperature value
            width = mTemperatureTextPaint.measureText(value);
            height += tempTopPadding + mPrecipitationTextPaint.getTextSize();

            canvas.drawText(value, xAxisValue - (width / 2), height, mTemperatureTextPaint);

            value = hour.getRainFallInInt() + "%"; // 10% for example
            int iconWidth = mPrecipitationIcon.getScaledWidth(canvas) + DeviceInfo.getValuesInPixel(2);
            // int iconWidth = DeviceInfo.getValuesInPixel(DeviceInfo.isDeviceAPhone() ? 12 : 18);
            width = iconWidth + mPrecipitationTextPaint.measureText(value);
            height += precipTopPadding;

            // No need to use the rectangle method here because the image is already in perfect size
            canvas.drawBitmap(mPrecipitationIcon, (xAxisValue - (width / 2)), height, null);

            mPrecipitationTextPaint.getTextBounds(value, 0, value.length(), mTextBounds);
            height += (mPrecipitationIcon.getScaledHeight(canvas) - mTextBounds.height()) / 2 + mTextBounds.height();
            canvas.drawText(value, (xAxisValue - (width / 2) + iconWidth), height, mPrecipitationTextPaint);

            xAxisValue += mHourlyDisplayWidth;
        }
    }

    private Path generatePath(int type, int startIndex) {
        pathValues.clear();
        tempGeneratePath.reset();

        if (type == TEMPERATURE) {
            pathValues.addAll(mTemperatureValues);
        } else if (type == PRECIPITATION) {
            pathValues.addAll(mPrecipitationValues);
        }
        tempGeneratePath.setFillType(Path.FillType.EVEN_ODD);

        float x = mHalfHourlyDisplayWidth;
        float y = getGraphHeightForValue(pathValues.get(startIndex));
        float x1 = mHourlyDisplayWidth + mHalfHourlyDisplayWidth; //1
        float y1 = getGraphHeightForValue(pathValues.get(startIndex + 1));
        float xControlPoint = (x + x1) / 2;
        float yControlPoint = (y + y1) / 2;

        if (startIndex == 0) {
            tempGeneratePath.moveTo(-1, y);  // start on edge of graph
            // path.moveTo(0, y);  // start on edge of graph
        } else {
            float lastY = getGraphHeightForValue(pathValues.get(pathValues.size() / 2 - 1));  // last point on left graph
            tempGeneratePath.moveTo(0, lastY);  // start at height of last value in left hand graph
        }
        tempGeneratePath.lineTo(x, y);
        tempGeneratePath.quadTo(xControlPoint, yControlPoint, x1, y1);

        for (int index = 1; index < pathValues.size() / 2 - 1; index++) {
            x = mHourlyDisplayWidth * index + mHalfHourlyDisplayWidth;  // current point
            y = getGraphHeightForValue(pathValues.get(index + startIndex));  // use start to get proper valye

            x1 = mHourlyDisplayWidth * (index + 1) + mHalfHourlyDisplayWidth;  // next point
            y1 = getGraphHeightForValue(pathValues.get(index + startIndex + 1));

            xControlPoint = (x + x1) / 2;  // control point
            yControlPoint = (y + y1) / 2;

            tempGeneratePath.quadTo(xControlPoint, yControlPoint, x1, y1);
        }

        // By going outside of viewable area, we can fill the precipitation path and draw a line on top
        tempGeneratePath.lineTo(x1 + mHourlyDisplayWidth, y1);  // add line at end, that goes past viewable area on left graph
        tempGeneratePath.lineTo(x1 + mHourlyDisplayWidth, mGraphHeightWithPadding); // below viewable area
        tempGeneratePath.lineTo(-5, mGraphHeightWithPadding); //below viewable area, to left of viewable area
        tempGeneratePath.close();

        return tempGeneratePath;
    }

    /**
     * Called in WeatherAdapter
     *
     * @param currentCityWeather      the weather data
     * @param onHourSelectionListener the listener to invoke when an hour is selected on the hourly forecast graph
     */
    public void setCurrentCityWeather(City currentCityWeather, OnHourSelectionListener onHourSelectionListener) {
        if (currentCityWeather == null) {
            return;
        }

        mCurrentCityWeather = currentCityWeather;
        mOnHourSelectionListener = onHourSelectionListener;
        mSelectedPosition = 0;

        ArrayList<Double> temperatureArray = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Double> precipitationArray = new ArrayList<>();

        if (currentCityWeather.hourlyForecast != null) {
            for (Hour hour : currentCityWeather.hourlyForecast) {
                if (hour != null) {
                    String weatherConditionIconUrl = myNews.getGlobal().manifest.appBaseUrls.getWeatherConditionIconUrl(hour.iconCode);
                    myNews.getVolleyHelper().getImageLoader().get(weatherConditionIconUrl, new ImageLoader.ImageListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(ImageLoader.ImageContainer imageContainer, boolean b) {
                            mWeatherConditionIcons.put(imageContainer.getRequestUrl(), imageContainer.getBitmap());
                            invalidate(); // Find a better way to draw these images. Do not invalidate the entire view all times
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {

                        }
                    });
                    temperatureArray.add(hour.getTemperatureInDouble());
                    precipitationArray.add(hour.getRainFallInDouble());
                } else {
                    temperatureArray.add(0.0);
                    precipitationArray.add(0.0);
                }
            }
        }

        // Set Values
        setTemperatureValues(temperatureArray);
        setPrecipitationValues(precipitationArray);

        // Redraw the view
        requestLayout();
        invalidate();
    }

    private void setTemperatureValues(ArrayList<Double> temperatureArray) {
        mTemperatureValues.clear();
        mTemperatureValues.addAll(temperatureArray);
    }

    private void setPrecipitationValues(ArrayList<Double> precipitationArray) {
        mPrecipitationValues.clear();
        mPrecipitationValues.addAll(precipitationArray);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event) || super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    /**
     * notifySelectionListener
     * User has selected an hour in the graph
     *
     * @param x the x position of the tap event
     * @param y the y position of the tap event
     * @return {@code true} if the selection is valid, {@code false} otherwise
     */
    private boolean notifySelectionListener(float x, float y) {
        return determineSelectedHour(x, y);
    }

    /**
     * determineSelectedHour
     * Based on coordinates on graph, determine the hour selected
     *
     * @param x the x position of the tap event
     * @param y the y position of the tap event
     * @return {@code true} if the selection is valid, {@code false} otherwise
     */
    private boolean determineSelectedHour(float x, float y) {
        // x is what matters
        // hour will be 0 to 23

        float graphWidth = numHours * mHourlyDisplayWidth;
        float selectedXProportion = x / graphWidth;
        float selectedHour = selectedXProportion * numHours;
        int selectHourInt = (int) selectedHour;

        if (0 <= selectedHour && selectedHour < numHours) {
            mSelectedPosition = selectHourInt;
            if (mOnHourSelectionListener != null) {
                mOnHourSelectionListener.onHourSelected(mSelectedPosition);
                myNews.getOmnitureHelper().sendClickAction(OmnitureConstants.FORECAST_LANDING_HOURLY_FORECAST_SWIPE_ACTION,
                        OmnitureConstants.FORECAST_LANDING_MODULE);
            }
            invalidate();  // this is what causes the redraw
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent event) {
            return notifySelectionListener(event.getX(), event.getY());
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of creating a bitmap, rendering to its canvas then drawing the bitmap on the view's canvas, why don't you turn off hardware acceleration, skip the bitmap step and just draw directly on the view's canvas?

Comment: I'll give it a shot tonight and let you know how it goes tomorrow

Comment: And he never did.